# Opening figure in a specific order

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

When the script run is over, all my figure appears in the opposite order. I mean I see the figure 3, then the figure 2 and the figure 1. 
But I would like to see figure 1 first and etc...

Is it possible ?

thank you.

Comment: Not really. You plot figure 1, then 2. This means that the last thing you put int he screen is figure 2, and that is what you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
y=rand([1,100];
x=1:100;

figure(1)
plot(x,y,'b')
figure(2)
plot(x,y,'r')
figure(3)
plot(x,y,'g')

% ...
% figure(N)
```

then in the end just do

```
N=3;
for ii=N-1:-1:1
   figure(ii)
end
```

Basically, calling `figure(existing_number)` will bring that figure upfront.

Comment: Great!! It works perfectly. Thank you !! @AnderBiguri